# How to change the way a counter is presented based on its value?

Tags: environments, conditionals, counters

I need an environment where the way the counter of the environment is presented changes according with the value of the counter. If the counter is less then 10 it must be succeeded by the ordinal mark “º”, otherwise it is printed without it.

I tryed using the `amsthm` and the `ifthen` packages to do this:

```
\newtheorem{artigo}{Art.}
\renewcommand{\theartigo}{%
\ifx\artigo<10%
\arabic{artigo}º%
\else%
\arabic{artigo}%
\fi%
}
```

But it is not working, I get “Art. 1”, instead of “Art. 1º”, when I use the environment `artigo`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\ifnum\value{artigo}<10\relax`, not `\ifx....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test for integer values is done with

`\ifnum counter value [relation] number ... \else ... \fi`

i.e.

```
\ifnum\value{artigo} < 10
  true branch
\else
  false branch
\fi
```

Alternatively one can use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theartigo}{%
  \ifnum\c@artigo<10
    \arabic{artigo}º%
  \else
    \arabic{artigo}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

to get rid off the `\value{artigo}` macro, but it has to price of `\makeatletter...\makeatother`, so there is no saving in typing ;-) (`\c@artigo` is the internal counter macro holding the value of the counter)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\newtheorem{artigo}{Art.}
\renewcommand{\theartigo}{%
  \ifnum\value{artigo}<10
    \arabic{artigo}º%
  \else
    \arabic{artigo}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{artigo}
Foo
\end{artigo}

\setcounter{artigo}{9}
\begin{artigo}
Foo again
\end{artigo}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\relax` makes this unexpandable; I fixed it.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I confused again with another occasion, where `\relax` is needed, but expansion is no issue.